# Rails Forms Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form and I also want to add a name field to this form. So when I ran my initial migration I didnt add name as a restaurant attribute but after (I think) I added name by running  "generate migration name column_name:restaurants"

```
<%= form_for(@restaurant) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :adress %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :adress %>
   </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :review %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :review %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

but I get a "undefined method `name' for #Restaurant:0x007fd5adc5e330" error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration command is wrong. Use this:

```
$ rails generate migration AddNameToRestaurant name:string
```

Then check the migration file manually to see if it is correct.

After model change, you need to run

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:test:prepare
```

Then your model change can take effect.

Comment: thanks, i used this one rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string, not sure if its the same, but problem solved !

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven，yes, Camal case and underscores are the same.